# How do I use accessToken retrieved from OIDCStrategy to traverse Azure Graph API?

Tags: node.js, azure, adal

I am using https://github.com/AzureAD/passport-azure-ad to integrate a nodejs application with Azure AD.

I used the OIDCStrategy to login a user into my node.js application.

Here's my code:

```
 (passport.use(new OIDCStrategy({
  callbackURL: config.azureadCreds.callbackURL,
  realm: config.azureadCreds.realm,
  clientID: config.azureadCreds.clientID,
  clientSecret: config.azureadCreds.clientSecret,
  scope: "openid offline_access profile Directory.Read UserProfile.Read",
  identityMetadata: config.azureadCreds.identityMetadata,
  skipUserProfile: config.azureadCreds.skipUserProfile,
  responseType: config.azureadCreds.responseType,
  responseMode: config.azureadCreds.responseMode,
  passReqToCallback: true
},
function (iss, sub, profile, claims, accessToken, refreshToken, params, done) {
  request.get("https://graph.windows.net/<my-tenant-id>/me?api-version=1.5", {
    'headers': {
      'Authorization': "Bearer " + params["id_token"],
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  }, function(err, res, body){
    if(err){
      console.log("err: " + err);
    }
    else{
      console.log("res: " + res);
    }
    done();
  });
 })));
```

However I am unable to get any response. I have tried a variety of configurations, but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Passport build on [Authorization Code Grant Flow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645542.aspx), and to get user profiles via Graph APIs, we need to build the application on [Service to Service Calls Using Client Credentials](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645543.aspx).

The access token gotten by  Authorization Code cannot be simply used as authorization in Graph APIs.

So we need to build custom HTTP requests for the access token via client_credentials, then leverage this token to traverse azure Graph APIs.

Build request to access token:
[image]

Use access token to traverse azure Graph APIs:

[image]

Comment: Ah.. I see. Makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: Wont someone PLEASE build an example because it doesn't make sense to me! I'm not a full-time developer, I just need access to the graph API's so I can pull out sensible data from O365. None of the MS examples are complete enough to use without needing massively more information and understanding.

Comment: Hi @JulianKnight, you can refer to http://dev.office.com/getting-started/office365apis . This site will help you to build a example project in the language you like.

Comment: Argh! Where did that come from! I've been searching for ages! Thank you SO much. Don't know how I missed it. So it uses the new ADAL.js library. Well that answers some questions as well.